# QSyntaxHighlighter: change background colour of the line where text cursor is

Tags: qt, qt4, syntax-highlighting, qtextedit

How to change the background colour of the line where text cursor (caret) is, using `QSyntaxHighlighter` and `QTextEdit`

Answer (score 1):

One way i found was using QTextEdit

```
QTextEdit *textEdit = centralWidget()->findChild<QTextEdit *>("textEdit");

QTextCursor textCursor(textEdit->document());
textCursor.select(QTextCursor::LineUnderCursor);

textEdit->setAutoFillBackground(true);
QPalette palette;
palette.setColor(QPalette::Background,QColor(200,200,200));
textEdit->setPalette(palette);
```

See if you find this usefull

Comment: fills at the edges, not behind the current line